# getting the number (1) after merging two associated arrays and printing the merged arrays using the print_r function in php

Tags: php

I get the number 1 after merging two associated arrays and printing the new merged array with the function print_r . I get this results

the code

```
<?php 

$test1 = ['Man1' => 'Old' , 'Man2' => 'young'];
$test2 = ['Man3' => 'Good' , 'Man4' => 'Bad'];
$test3 = array_merge($test1,$test2);
echo print_r($test3);

?>
```

the results :

```
Array ( [Man1] => Old [Man2] => young [Man3] => Good [Man4] => Bad ) 1
```

why I get the 1 at the end ?

Comment: Remove the `echo`

Comment: thank you . But it's intresting for me to know why I get it not how to remove it. please read my question again.

Comment: `print_r()` prints the array and returns `TRUE`. `echo` then prints `TRUE`, which is converted to `1`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar ;)

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with merging arrays. You would see the same thing if you did `echo print_r($test1);` without merging.

Answer (score 0):

The `echo` is printing the 1 coming from `print_r`